# Unable to add codesniffer, psr-1, psr-2, pmd rules in sonarqube

Tags: php, sonarqube, pmd, phpcodesniffer, psr-1

Need to add codesniffer, psr-1, psr-2, pmd rules in sonarqube. I tried finding plugin but get sonar-php-codesniffer0.2 plugin which is compatible only upto sonarqube>2.0. Also there is no way to import custom php rules in sonarqube6.1 or updated versions. How can now i add these rules to sonarqube for code quality analysis?

Comment: Please provide some solution

Comment: I am trying to make sonarqube plugin for it, please provide some link where i can get enough content to make plugin. Documentation is not enough to make plugin to add coding rules of PHP as mentioned above.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new plugin which imports issues from other tools (like CodeSniffer) into SonarQube.

See for example https://github.com/SonarQubeCommunity/sonar-cppcheck or https://github.com/Designite/sonar-designite-plugin.

Moreover you can create your own custom rules ([docs](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Custom+Rules+for+PHP)) for SonarPHP.

Note that SonarPHP already has some coverage for psr-1 and psr-2 ([rules list](https://sonarqube.com/coding_rules#languages=php%7Ctags=psr2%2Cpsr1)).